# how does google decide in which mobile my app will be available to install? i.e minimum device hardware requirement

Tags: android, system, require, minimum

we develop apps for android version 7 and above.
we test our app on many devices. strangely, we have seen that on some of the devices our app is not available to install on google market (play store).
the question is, that does google decide this by calculating the system (device) requirement or are we doing something wrong.

our AndroidManifest.xml file contains this line with other usual ones.
uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="11"

Comment: What is your minSDK for app and what is the SDK on devices where you don't see your app?

Comment: What I know is that api level, and are filters used in playstore

Comment: You need to show us the rest of your manifest. Either that, or you can go to your google play developer console. It will tell you why your app is not accessible to all the devices.

Comment: May I kindly ask you to accept my answer, if it's meet with your expectations. Thank you very much

Comment: I had clicked it immediately. But stackoverflow showed me a short period message that i couldn't read (may be saying i must reach higher reputation number!).

Comment: Yes your answer helped me. But, i have edited the question after your answer. Added - minimum device hardware requirement (like RAM / processor). This question arose because - in a device (old mobile) with API 7, having low internal memory and RAM, our application wasn't shown in market (now called as play store).

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for Google Play Filters.

> When a user searches or browses for apps to download on Google Play, the results are filtered based on which applications are compatible with the device. For example, if an app requires a camera, Google Play would not show the app to devices that do not have a camera. This filtering helps developers manage the distribution of their apps and helps ensure the best possible experience for users.
>
> Filtering in Google Play is based on several types of app metadata and configuration settings, including manifest declarations, required libraries,architecture dependencies, and distribution controls set in the Google Play Developer Console, such as geographic targeting, pricing, and more.

Please find the official article from Google here:
http://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html

Comment: Your answer helped me. But, i edited the question after you answered. I added - minimum device hardware requirement (like RAM / processor).